# NSManagedObject subclass with failable init in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a NSManagedObject subclass, which needs to be fulfilled before to return correctly (it has all of their fields as non-optionals), so when I do the init, first of all I use a guard to be sure of the data (from JSON) is correct as follow:

```
public init(context: NSManagedObjectContext, dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) throws {
    guard
    let modified_on = date(dictionary["modified_on"] as? String),
    let start_on = date(dictionary["start_on"] as? String),
    let end_on = date(dictionary["end_on"] as? String),
    let ticket_name = dictionary["ticket_name"] as? String
    else {
        throw ErrorParseModel.ErrorParsing
    }
...
...
```

The problem is that compiler returns me an error `Super.init isn't called before returning from initializer` because it's possible that this init method throws an exception without to call `super.init` before.

My dude is about how to proceed:
1. Should I call super.init before and create a "dummy object" before than guard? On this case, I should to remove this object from context before to throw exception?
2. Another test that I could do before of this guard is to be sure that entityName is correct as follows:

```
guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(Ticket.entityName, inManagedObjectContext: context) else {
   return
}
```

On this case, I can't to create the object in the context because I don't have entity, so it's impossible (I think) to create a nil-entity object in one context.

Any suggestion about how can I proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Super.init isn't called before returning from initializer" problem
can be solved by implementing a *convenience* initializer instead
of a dedicated initializer:

```
public convenience init(context: NSManagedObjectContext, dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) throws {
    guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(Ticket.entityName, inManagedObjectContext: context) else {
        throw ErrorParseModel.EntityNotFound
    }
    guard
        let modified_on = date(dictionary["modified_on"] as? String)
        // ...
    else {
        throw ErrorParseModel.ErrorParsing
    }
    self.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    self.modified_on = modified_on
}
```

However, in my opinion it does not make much sense to throw an error
if the Core Data entity is not found. That would be a *programming
error* and there is no sensible way to catch and resolve that problem
at runtime. I would treat that as a fatal error, so that
it is detected early while testing the app:

```
    guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(Ticket.entityName, inManagedObjectContext: context) else {
        fatalError("Entity not found")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin R, that makes sense! :)